# Post-Calculations on Aggregations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and I feel stucked in simple operations that I would solve in regular SQL using subqueries.

How can I subtract the two resulting rows? I have grouped the results and I would like to return the difference between them:

```
MATCH (seguidores:RelevantTwitterUser {location:"Madrid"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(seguidos:RelevantTwitterUser {location:"Barcelona"}) 
WITH COLLECT({origen:seguidores.location, user:seguidores.userId}) AS ROWS
MATCH (seguidores:RelevantTwitterUser {location:"Barcelona"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(seguidos:RelevantTwitterUser {location:"Madrid"}) 
WITH ROWS + COLLECT({origen:seguidores.location, user:seguidores.userId}) AS allRows
UNWIND allRows AS ROW
RETURN ROW.origen, COUNT(ROW.user)
```

with the output:

[image: output example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer using [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/)

```
WITH "Madrid" AS loc1, "Barcelona" AS loc2
MATCH (:RelevantTwitterUser{location:loc1})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:RelevantTwitterUser{location:loc2})
WITH loc1, loc2, COUNT(*) AS count1
MATCH (:RelevantTwitterUser{location:loc2})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:RelevantTwitterUser{location:loc1})
WITH loc1, loc2, count1, COUNT(*) AS count2
RETURN loc1, count1, loc2, count2, count1 - count2 AS diff
```

You should read the documentation on [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COUNT`) if you want to understand how this query works, and to avoid getting the wrong counts if you need to modify this query. It is especially important to understand how `grouping keys` (e.g., `locs` and `count` in the last `WITH` clause) affect the behavior of aggregating functions.

#### Answer using [SIZE() on pattern expressions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-size-of-pattern-expression)

```
WITH "Madrid" AS loc1, "Barcelona" AS loc2
WITH loc1, loc2,
  SIZE((:RelevantTwitterUser{location:loc1})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:RelevantTwitterUser{location:loc2})) AS count1,
  SIZE((:RelevantTwitterUser{location:loc2})-[:FOLLOWS]->(:RelevantTwitterUser{location:loc1})) AS count2
RETURN loc1, count1, loc2, count2, count1 - count2 AS diff
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for both answers. 

The first one was the attempt I was trying to perform what I was messing up with UNION and COLLECT. Thanks for that one, is very clarifying.

The second one is more elegant, I will read about SIZE, it has a very convenient grammar.